# How can I delete a column of a Dataset?

Tags: c#, .net, dataset

How can I delete a column of a Dataset?

Is there a method that will do this for me like this:

```
rh.dsDetail = ds.Tables[0].Columns.Remove(
```

Or maybe like this:

```
rh.dsDetail = ds.Tables[0].Columns.Remove( ds.Tables[0].Columns[1],ds.Tables[0].Columns[2])
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First, a `DataTable` has columns, not a data-set.

If you want to get rid of them, then:

```
table.Columns.Clear();
```

otherwise, if you have the index:

```
table.Columns.RemoveAt(0);
```

should do the job if you have the column index. Note that if you remove column 0, then the numbers will shuffle (so you might need to do in reverse order).

Alternatively, you may want to remove by name:

```
table.Columns.Remove("Foo");
```

Answer (score 4):

I have done this before in both winforms & web apps. You must go thru the DataTable in reverse and then do an AcceptChanges at the end. This particular example is typical, in that it removes all the GUIDs (columns ending with "id").

```
    private void RemoveUselessFields(ref DataTable dtResults)
    {
        for (int i = dtResults.Columns.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            DataColumn column = dtResults.Columns[i];
            if (column.ColumnName.Substring(column.ColumnName.Length - 2, 2).ToUpper() == "ID") 
            {
                dtResults.Columns.Remove(column);
            }
        }
        dtResults.AcceptChanges();

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no built in method to remove more than one column at a time. You can create an extension method though if you'd like. Something like this:

```
 public static class DataColumnCollectionExtensions
    {
        public static void RemoveColumns(this DataColumnCollection column, params string[] columns)
        {
            foreach (string c in columns)
            {
                column.Remove(c);
            }
        }
    }
```

You can then use it like this:

```
DataTable table1 = ds.Tables[0];
table1.Columns.RemoveColumns("Column1","Column2","Column6");
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no such method. But you can simply write your own Helpermethod

```
public static void RemoveColumns(DataTable dt, params DataColumn[] dc)
{
    foreach (DataColumn c in dc)
    {
        dt.Columns.Remove(c);
    }
}

RemoveColumns(ds.Tables[0], ds.Tables[0].Columns[1], ds.Tables[0].Columns[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

if ever you want to delete the columns because you have new set of columns names, you can use this:

```
DataSet.Reset();
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In python, there is a package called pandas.
It has a function called drop. `pandas.dataframe.drop(labels=None, axis=0, index=None, columns=None, level=None, inplace=False, errors='raise')`
Here, use the name of the column to be dropped at labels="column name".

refer more in pandas documentation :https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html